# Remap any key to win

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, linux-mint, keyboard-layout, remapping

I've tried a lot of combinations to map my key AE12 to Super (win key) but all them failed...

How can i map a key to act like win key in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us ?

I am using linux mint.

details on [github](https://github.com/AlexParamonov/config/commit/53196e0f47d9c172ed2fa9ac1fc3dae37cd9d1be)

~~~~

Noticed that after reboot layout reverts to previous version plus it displays wrong layout on keyboard graphical layout representation. If after reboot i remove my layout and add it back thought menu then it applies and keys are remapped correctly. But in graphical representation it remains old. After new reboot - same story.

Maybe i need to clean some cache?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your `~/.Xmodmap`

```
keycode 21 = Super_L
add mod4 = Super_L
```

Then make sure your desktop manager parses it at start. If it doesn't, add to you `~/.xinitrc`

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

In your key AE12's `keycode` isn't `21`, use `xev` to find out the right code. In my case, that key is the key immediately to the left of the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key.

Comment: great, but is there a way to map it in layout file? I want to keep all  remaps in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use my machine for a while. And when it was booted, my mappings were working like a charm. So it seems was a cache issue...